# Is it bad practice to use Object.getClass() in Java?

Tags: java, reflection, rtti

I am well aware of the fact that **reflection** should only be used as a last resort, and even if you are in a situation where it seems you should rely on it may imply bad design on your part. It's a very powerful tool that **should only be used with extreme caution**.

I am also aware that **Java stores** some **housekeeping information** about objects, so in theory it should be a relatively cheap operation to determine the dynamic type of an object with `Object.getClass()` (at least cheap compared to languages without such housekeeping data, for example C++, where expensive vtable lookups are needed for RTTI).

Is this really the case? **Is it** considered **bad** practice in Java **to check if an objec**t of some base **is a certain** derived **type** using `getClass()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking runtime type of the object is considered a bad practice in cases when you try to choose a behavior based on the type:

```
if (animal instanceof Cat) { // or animal.getClass() == Cat.class
   ((Cat) animal).meow();
} else if (animal instanceof Dog) {
   ((Dog) animal).woof();
}
```

If you do this, you ignore polymorphism, because it tells to do this instead:

```
animal.makeSound();
```

But there can be a lot of cases when you need to know the object type and use `.getClass()` and `instanceof` - when using reflections, working with third party libraries, etc. If you're not hacking polymorphism, you're fine.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it depends entirely on the situation, but most cases I've seen, are bad practice cases. Because it is usually used a a replacement for proper design.

An example case of a bad practice use of `getClass` would be something like this:

```
public void method(SomeObject obj) {
    if(obj.getClass() == A.class) {
        // do something for A
    }
    if(obj.getClass() == B.class) {
        // do something for B
    }
    ...
}
```

Why not delegate to `obj`:

```
obj.doSomething();
```

Or split cases by overloading methods:

```
public void method(A obj){...}
public void method(B obj){...}
```

The point is, it can be avoided a lot of the time, and it's usually a sign that you're doing work at runtime that can instead be done at compile time.

Comment: What do you think about using `getClass()` to check for equality (e.g. while overriding the `equals()` method)?

Answer (score 0):

It is not considered a bad practice to check the type of an Object. However, reflection in Java is still considered an expensive operation.

Instead of using `getClass()` to determine a type, it is a better practice to use `instanceof` to check if a type matches what you are looking for.

For example:

```
if(theObject instanceof SomeBaseClassObject){
    //do something
}
```

Comment: `instanceof` returns `true` for an instance of a class derived from the class `SomeBaseClassObject`as well, so it is not the same.

Comment: Correct, but you would use it to check the level in the parent/child hierarchy you care about. If you want to verify it is a child object then instanceof on that. You can narrow the scope as desired.

Comment: Correct but one would use `getClass()` to check if an instance is _exactly_ of the type one looks for.

Comment: Never said you couldn't. I just said it is preferred to use instanceof :)